# Backward Elimination and plotting an ANCOVA model

Tags: r

I have the following data set:

https://pastebin.com/embed_js/tjf5dyV4

```
dput(Cars[1:10, c("MPG", "BHP", "TSP", "CAR")])
structure(list(MPG = c(22.989377, 23.472416, 23.777477, 21.697264, 
21.031248, 23.856801, 11.427261, 26.180126, 22.121896, 17.399829
), BHP = c(110L, 110L, 93L, 110L, 175L, 105L, 245L, 62L, 95L, 
123L), TSP = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CAR = c(4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I took the Log Transformation (I did not transform TSP and CAR) of the above and got the following:

https://pastebin.com/embed_js/6mmiakg3

```
dput(LogData[1:10, c("Y", "X3", "X9", "X10")])
structure(list(Y = c(3.13503223966933, 3.15582594448829, 3.16873878807292, 
3.07718616964798, 3.04600933174841, 3.17206933391746, 2.43600181654432, 
3.2650005733044, 3.09656788726659, 2.85646037858599), X3 = c(4.70048036579242, 
4.70048036579242, 4.53259949315326, 4.70048036579242, 5.16478597392351, 
4.65396035015752, 5.50125821054473, 4.12713438504509, 4.55387689160054, 
4.81218435537242), X9 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), X10 = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

---

After my backwards elim, I got the final model of lm(Y ~ X3+X9+X10)

Where X3 is a continuous explanatory variable and X9 and X10 being categorical explanatory variables.
I want to plot the fitted lines from this Final Model, together with the observed data.

I am unsure how to approach this, how would one go about doing this?

Comment: I would suggest deleting all the parts about backward selection as they don't seem to be related to your question. Also the untransformed data is pretty irrelevant (unless that's what you want to plot??). Focus your question on just the data you want to plot and the model you want to plot.

Comment: Also, it would be much nicer if you would provide an excerpt of data in the question, preferably using `dput` so it is copy-pasteable. `dput(Cars[1:10, c("MPG", "BHP", "TSP", "CAR")])` will give us the first 10 rows of data, relevant columns only, in a format that is copy/pasteable, and will keep the question self-contained even if the pastebin links go down.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback! I am new here so I wasn't sure if I have applied your feedback correctly, but I have tried. I hope the current edited form is better :)

Comment: Much better, thanks! So, you say `X9` and `X10` are categorical, but their data type is integer so they are being treated as continuous (thanks to the `dput` we can see the classes). So, I think you should probably convert all of your categorical columns to `factor` class and make sure this is really the model you want to use.

Comment: (Showing the model summary is nice too.. from that I could see that you had 1 coefficient for `X9` and one for `X10`, but if they were categorical than you should have one coefficient *per level* of the factor minus one (for the intercept).